# UTF-8 issue in sending local language message in chat application?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets, utf-8

In my Chat application I need to send message in local language.

It works fine ,when trying to send a message to agent and displayed exactly it in the Customer Side.

But at agent side in displays   à®¨à¯à®à¯à®à®³à¯ à®à®ªà¯à®ªà®à®¿ à®à®°à¯à®à¯à®à®¿à®±à¯à®°à¯à®à®³à¯ for நீங்கள் எப்படி இருக்கிறீர்கள்(in english - how are you)...

In my jsp page I used,

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%> 
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8; ">
<title>Initializer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div><textarea id="textarea" rows="10" readonly></textarea></div>
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="msg" class="fontStyle">message :</td>
        <td id="msgvalue"><input size="40" type="text" id="message"
            onkeydown="enterKey()" /></td>
        <td style="width: 5%;"></td>
        <td>
        <center><input type="button" id="button3"
            onclick="sendMessage()" value="Send" /></center>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

In java script,

```
function sendMessage(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(function(){pingAction();},5000);
    message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    document.getElementById("message").innerText = "";
    //document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML = message;
    //alert("---------->"+sessionId+userId+secureKey+message);
    //alert("msg ---> : "+ message);
    try
    {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            //alert("Status : "+xmlhttp.status+"\nreadyState : "+xmlhttp.readyState);
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                //alert("Message ----> : "+xmlhttp.responseText.toString());
                //alert("Decoded Message----> : "+decodeURIComponent(xmlhttp.responseText.toString()));
                //var checkMsg = decodeURIComponent(xmlhttp.responseText.toString());
                var checkMsg = xmlhttp.responseText.toString();
                if(checkMsg != "null" && checkMsg != null){
                    //document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML +=  checkMsg;
                    if(textarea.value == "")
                        textarea.value = checkMsg;
                    else
                        textarea.value += "\n"+ checkMsg;
                }
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("POST","SendMessageAction?sessionId="+sessionId+"&userId="+userId+"&securekey="+secureKey+"&message="+encodeURIComponent(message)+"&sid="+Math.random(),true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("charset","UTF-8");        
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err.description);
    }
}
```

In my servlet,

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        msg = request.getParameter("message");
        //System.out.println("msg -----> : "+msg);
        seckey = request.getParameter("securekey");
        uid = request.getParameter("userId");
        sessionId = request.getParameter("sessionId");
        //counter =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("counter"));
        counter = 1;
        protocol = ApplicationInfo.flexProtocol;

        message = new SendMessage();
        message.send(msg, seckey, uid, sessionId, counter, protocol);

        CustomerInfo customer = ApplicationInfo.customerDetails.get(uid);

        out.print(customer.getMessage());


    }
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: at the top of your `doPost` function, try `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`

Comment: I already tried that.But getting the same message...

Comment: Am I want to set anything in my tomcat6.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *But at agent side in displays à®¨à¯à®à¯à®à®³à¯ à®à®ªà¯à®ªà®à®¿ à®à®°à¯à®à¯à®à®¿à®±à¯à®°à¯à®à®³à¯ for நீங்கள் எப்படி இருக்கிறீர்கள்(in english - how are you)...*

You will get exactly this result when ISO-8859-1 is incorrectly been used to decode the given characters to bytes before transmitting them over the HTTP line, or when the client is incorrectly been instructed to ust ISO-8859-1 to encode the retrieved bytes to characters. Here's the evidence:

```
System.out.println(new String("நீங்கள் எப்படி இருக்கிறீர்கள்".getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1"));
```

You basically need to instruct the servlet container to use UTF-8 to decode the given characters to bytes **and** the client to use UTF-8 to encode the retrieved bytes to characters. It would otherwise default to ISO-8859-1. This can be done in the servlet as follows, *before* you write anything to the response:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you've other potential encoding problems; you haven't instructed your JSP to render the response using UTF-8 as well. Only setting the `@page contentType` is not sufficient, you also need to set the `@page pageEncoding`. Even more, setting alone it is already sufficient as JSP already defaults to `text/html`.

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Once you've fixed that, then you should add another line to the servlet code, *before* the first `request.getParameter()` call ever in order to instruct the container to use UTF-8 to encode the request parameters.

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Also note that the HTML `<meta>` tag is **not** been used when the page is served over HTTP. It's plain ignored. It's only been used when the enduser saves the HTML output to a HTML file on disk and then reopens it from disk by `file://` URI.

Comment: When I include the ,  request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); in my Servlet, I got the same message à®¨à¯à®à¯à®à®³à¯ à®à®ªà¯à®ªà®à®¿ à®à®°à¯à®à¯à®à®¿à®±à¯à®°à¯à®à®³à¯ in my Client side also.Both side I got same message..

Comment: Uh, have you **read** the answer instead of only looking at the last occurring code block?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you've changed based on the provided answer. Have you changed everything or only the response encoding? It's recommendable to change everything exactly as mentioned in the answer. Please note that the timing matters very much, as already hinted in my answer. If you set the response encoding after obtaining the response writer for the first time, then it's too late. If you set the request encoding after obtaining any request parameter for the first time, then it's too late. Check the filters as well, if any.

Comment: Am I want to set anything in my tomcat6.0 ?

Comment: I got the solution,I just added the line in my servlet as msg = new String((request.getParameter("message")).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8"); and working fine.

Comment: This is not a solution. This is a workaround. This indicates that you didn't properly set the page encoding or the request encoding. You don't need to set anything in Tomcat in case of POST requests.

Comment: Thanks for reply...But how can I track ,Where my bug was?I included all the steps u said above..not not worked...After using  msg = new String((request.getParameter("message")).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");  only , I got the solution...Could you please help me to clear the problem...

Comment: As answered and commented, you need to ensure that `request.setCharacterEncoding()` is called **before** the request body is accessed for the first time, otherwise it's too late. Perhaps you're accessing the request body beforehand in some servlet filter. The best place to set the character encoding would then be another servlet filter which is invoked as first filter in the chain.

Comment: Thanks for your supporting brother...having one more doubt? How to set request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); in my jsp ?

Comment: No, Java code doesn't belong in a JSP file. It belongs in a Java class. Put it in your servlet class, **before** any `request.getParameter()` call.